How to deal with rabbitmq 4.0 deprecations?
I am using rabbitmq with celery. When rabbitmq starts, I see the following warning:
Deprecated features: `transient_nonexcl_queues`: Feature `transient_nonexcl_queues` is deprecated.
By default, this feature can still be used for now.
Its use will not be permitted by default in a future minor RabbitMQ version and the feature will be removed from a future major RabbitMQ version; actual versions to be determined.
To continue using this feature when it is not permitted by default, set the following parameter in your configuration:
    "deprecated_features.permit.transient_nonexcl_queues = true"
To test RabbitMQ as if the feature was removed, set this in your configuration:
    "deprecated_features.permit.transient_nonexcl_queues = false"

I also get the same warning about global_qos. If I set both keys to false as in the warning, I get errors, so apparantly I am using these features. But I am not conciously using them: I don't really care if my queue is transient or exclusive or not, and I have not configured QoS. I just want to submit tasks from python and have them run in the background. If the message broker crashes then that's not ideal, but it is not the end of the world. It's on the same physical server as the rest of the app anyway.
How can I "just make this warning go away" and keep my configuration future proof (so not just by setting both to true)? I have not found related settings in rabbitmq.conf, so I'm guessing I have to change the way I access the queue from Python?

I was able to run RabbitMQ without some deprecated features adding the following to the values.yaml (if using Helm):
configuration: |-
  deprecated_features.permit.transient_nonexcl_queues = false

To disable using the rabbitmq.conf, the official GitHub RabbitMQ repository includes the lines you need for configuring it. In your case, it should be:
  deprecated_features.permit.global_qos = false
  ...

